# Any method to enabled n28b band on MIUI phone?

Tags: networking, miui, network-signal, bandwidth

Actually, I'm not sure if n28a and n28b are in the n28 band, or if they're different in the first place (even though the frequencies are both 700). Because the cell phone info sites I know of usually don't directly state whether they support n28a or n28b, but rather use n28 as a catch-all...

I'm in Malaysia, and my current phone is a Redmi Note 11T Pro China Version, and according to this [Malaysia 5G supported bands](https://www.kimovil.com/en/frequency-checker/MY/xiaomi-redmi-note-11t-pro), my current phone's U Mobile only doesn't support n26 and n28b, and according to this [U Mobile 5G Compatible Devices](https://www.u.com.my/en/personal/devices/5g-devices-original). I then used this [Malaysia 5G Supported Bands](https://www.kimovil.com/en/frequency-checker/MY/xiaomi-redmi-note-11t-pro) website to check for supported phones and also found many phones that support n28b but not n26. I strongly suspect that I can't receive 5G signal because it don't support n28b band!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phones are locked for bands because they are not allowed to use other bands in that country. So they can be locked by the manufacturer or Telco/Provider.

Even if you can unlock it, it may not have the right antenna.

Comment: The antenna should be indeed the problem, optimizing it for multiple frequencies is to my knowledge pretty complicated so manufacturers limit the number of frequencies a phone can be used with. So even if it would be possible to unlock those frequencies the connection speed using those frequencies would be awful (or even not working at all).